# Symfony 2.3 - Disable bundles based on service data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I would like to disable some bundles based on the data stored in database.
I know I can do that based on the environment:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle()             );

        // Environment based bundles
        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

However that doesn't obviously answer this question, can I inject services into `AppKernel` itself? Or can I inject them into bundle itself and somehow disable it?

Comment: Why would you need to disable some bundles? Can't you have your switching logic on a lower level?

Comment: For example, I want only to attach some events to the entities during specific dates.

Comment: That doesn't really explain to me why would you need to disable the bundles completely - Symfony won't load any unnecessary classes you don't use. So just instantiate what you need later on.

Comment: If you create an event and attach it to for example entity, it just hooks up to the entity life-cycle. So I'd have to write some special exceptions in the event itself to avoid its functionality. Disabling bundle seems much cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

If I was you, I would do the following

1. Create a simple bundle, which would handle the request to the database and all such stuff
2. Register this bundle in [`app/AppKernel`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/app/AppKernel.php)
3. Create `YourKernel` class and extend it from [`app/AppKernel`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/app/AppKernel.php)
4. "Inject" `YourKernel` it into [`web/app.php`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/2.3/web/app.php#L19)
5. In `YourKernel` redefine [`boot()`](https://github.com/symfony/HttpKernel/blob/2.3/Kernel.php#L116-L138) method, in which you would get the list of bundle and boot needed ones, dependent on the returned value.

Comment: Could you expand your solution with some boilerplate code? I don't see how does that changes things, still, that's probably my lack of knowledge.